# Create an Excel file on disk without "SaveAs"

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to create an Excel file on disk? I can't use the typical `NewBook.SaveAs` because my document management system hook grabs it whenever a SaveAs operation is present. I can however open a document on disk and save with the original filename.

I could use `ActiveWorkbook.Save` which is what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: `SaveCopyAs` ?  It would help to explain a little more exactly what it is you're doing.

Comment: What about copying an existing file using the [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264639.aspx) statement, and then opening that file, making your changes, and doing the `Workbook.Save`?

Comment: "whenever a *save as object is present*" - uh, "save as" is a *method*, the *object* is `Workbook`. Care to expand on your "document management system"? Is that a `Workbook_BeforeSave` event handler at application level (i.e. an Excel add-in)? Other than that, it's like @tigeravatar said: use the `VBA.FileSystem` module members to work with the files directly, without going through the Excel object model.

Comment: Hi. To clarify;

The Document Management System (Humingbird) hijacks your document when you try to "Save As" and tries to put the document in a repository as opposed to the hard drive. I have to do a lot of manipulation (via VBA) before it's ready to go into the DM system. 


`NewBook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=FName`

Works great! Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's unclear what you're trying to do (or why), here's a hack that might be useful as it does not invoke `SaveAs` or `SaveCopyAs` (not sure if the latter is a problem for your DMS):

```
Dim sPath$, sFileName$, newFileName$
sPath = "C:\Path\Where\You\Want\YourFileSaved\"
sFileName = "MyExcelFile.xlsx"
'The Worksheet.Copy method will create a new Excel file
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Copy
'Specify the path where you'd like the file to be
ChDir sPath
'Saves the file with default name e.g., "Book2.xlsx", etc.
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Rename the file if needed, first get the file's default name:
newFileName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
'Close it so we can rename it
ActiveWorkbook.Close
'Rename it:
Name newFileName As sFileName
```